# Concatenating row values in x++

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

In AX 2012, Is there a way to display values from multiple rows in a single column like the way we have in SQL by using 'stuff' and 'for xml path keywords':

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing. It cannot be done using X++ SQL alone.

Feel free to loop around and use a map of sets.